# How to use a list of variables with dplyr across?

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, across

I feel like there should be a very simple way to do this, but I can't figure this out. I want to use `across` with a list of variables and tidyselect helpers in a large dataset, but I'll use `iris` as an example.

Before the dplyr 1.0 update, I could successfully use scoped verbs like this:

```
VARS <- vars(Sepal.Length, starts_with("Petal"))
iris %>% 
  mutate_at(VARS, as.character)
```

I thought `iris %>% mutate(across(!!!VARS, as.character))` would work but I get an error. I know the update supersedes `vars`, but I'm not able to save the variables with `list` or `c`.

Please help! Looking for an elegant tidyverse solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options for you to choose.

```
library(dplyr)
VARS1 <- quote(c(Sepal.Length, starts_with("Petal")))
VARS2 <- expr(c(Sepal.Length, starts_with("Petal")))
VARS3 <- quo(c(Sepal.Length, starts_with("Petal")))
```

Output

```
> iris %>% mutate(across(!!VARS1, as.character)) %>% str()
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: chr  "5.1" "4.9" "4.7" "4.6" ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: chr  "1.4" "1.4" "1.3" "1.5" ...
 $ Petal.Width : chr  "0.2" "0.2" "0.2" "0.2" ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

> iris %>% mutate(across(!!VARS2, as.character)) %>% str()
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: chr  "5.1" "4.9" "4.7" "4.6" ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: chr  "1.4" "1.4" "1.3" "1.5" ...
 $ Petal.Width : chr  "0.2" "0.2" "0.2" "0.2" ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

> iris %>% mutate(across(!!VARS3, as.character)) %>% str()
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: chr  "5.1" "4.9" "4.7" "4.6" ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: chr  "1.4" "1.4" "1.3" "1.5" ...
 $ Petal.Width : chr  "0.2" "0.2" "0.2" "0.2" ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Answer (score 3):

`vars` has been superseded since dplyr 1.0.0. You can directly use the column names as string or unquoted variables in `across`.

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
  mutate(across(c(Sepal.Length, starts_with("Petal")), as.character))
```

If you want to save the variables first and then apply the function you can do.

```
VARS <- c('Sepal.Length', grep('^Petal', names(iris), value = TRUE))

iris %>% mutate(across(VARS, as.character))
```

Comment: I'm specifically looking for an answer that saves the column names as a variable, then calls them in the across

Comment: @KateHam See updated answer. Would that help for your purpose?